# Can one drop rows in a dataframe based on nunique values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I want to ignore the rows is the occupation has less than 2 unique names:

```
name        value      occupation
   a           23      mechanic
   a           24      mechanic
   b           30      mechanic
   c           40      mechanic
   c           41      mechanic
   d           30      doctor
   d           20      doctor
   e           70      plumber
   e           71      plumber
   f           30      plumber
   g           50      tailor
```

I did:

```
df.groupby('ocuupation')['name'].nunique()
>>>>>>
occupation
mechanic   3
doctor     1
plumber    2
tailor     1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Is it possible to use something like `df = df.drop(df[<some boolean condition>].index)`?

Desired output:

```
name        value      occupation
   a           23      mechanic
   a           24      mechanic
   b           30      mechanic
   c           40      mechanic
   c           41      mechanic
   e           70      plumber
   e           71      plumber
   f           30      plumber
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for get values equal of greater like `2`:

```
df = df[df.groupby('occupation')['name'].transform('nunique').ge(2)]
print (df)
  name  value occupation
0    a     23   mechanic
1    a     24   mechanic
2    b     30   mechanic
3    c     40   mechanic
4    c     41   mechanic
7    e     70    plumber
8    e     71    plumber
9    f     30    plumber
```

Your solution is filtered values of index in Series compared in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
s = df.groupby('occupation')['name'].nunique()

df = df[df['occupation'].isin(s[s.ge(2)].index)]
print (df)
  name  value occupation
0    a     23   mechanic
1    a     24   mechanic
2    b     30   mechanic
3    c     40   mechanic
4    c     41   mechanic
7    e     70    plumber
8    e     71    plumber
9    f     30    plumber
```